# JSON:API HTTP status code for duplicate content creation avoidance

Tags: api, duplicates, json-api, http-response-codes, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I have an endpoint that supports creating new messages. I am avoiding the creation of two times the same message in the backend, in case the user tries to push the button twice (or in case the frontend app behaves strangely).

Currently for the duplicate action my server is responding with a 303 see other pointing to the previously created resource URL. But I see I could also use a 302 found. Which one seems more appropriate ?

Note that the duplicate avoidance strategy can be more complex (eg for an appointment we would check whether the POSTed appointment is within one hour of an existing one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using HTTP Status Code 409: Conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The 3XX family of status codes are generally used when the client needs to take additional action, such as redirection, to complete the request. More generally, status codes communicate back to the client what actions they need to take or provide them with necessary information about the request.

Generally for these kind of "bad" requests (such as repeated requests failing due to duplication) you would respond with a 400 status code to indicate to the client that there was an issue with their request and it was not processed. You could use the response to communicate more precisely the issue.

Also to consider, if the request is just "fire and forget" from the client then as long as you've handled the case for duplication and no more behavior is needed from the client it might be acceptable to send a 200 response. This tells the client "the request was received and handled appropriately, nothing more you need to do." However this is a bit deceptive as it does not indicate the error to the client or allow for any modified behavior.

Comment: So you'd go with a 400 and eventually send a link to the original non-duplicate content ? Also I'm using Jsonapi in case this provide additional rules... I was thinking the 300 would be a good alternative between the 400 and the 200. When I'm testing with postman the 300 code automatically gets replayed to the redirect URL and I'm wondering if this is automatically done by the HTTP layer or if it's something that can be detected easily in the javascript...

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating-responses-409) defines:

> A server **MUST** return 409 Conflict when processing a POST request to create a resource with a client-generated ID that already exists.